# Install netbeans from a private IP machine in another remote public IP machine using SSH

Tags: linux, ssh, remote-desktop, centos, netbeans

I am sitting in a private IP machine (local) and want to install [netbeans](https://netbeans.org/) in another remote public IP machine (remote). The local machine runs Ubuntu and the remote machine runs CentOS.

I have downloaded the [netbeans installer](http://download.netbeans.org/netbeans/8.1/final/bundles/netbeans-8.1-linux.sh) in the remote machine and changed it to an executable one.

Now, in remote, when I issue the command,

```
# ./netbeans-8.1-linux.sh
```

I get an error message,

> No X11 DISPLAY variable was set, but this program performed an
>   operation which requires it.

To take care of this, in remote, I run,

```
# export DISPLAY=:0
```

In local, I run,

```
$ xhost +
```

and rerun the installer in remote turning on the verbose flag,

```
./netbeans-8.1-linux.sh --verbose
```

This gives the error message,

> Can't connect to X11 window server using ':0' as the value of the
>   DISPLAY variable.

*(I tried other variations like `0.0`).*

As some searching over the net reveals, my only option left is, in remote, to issue the command,

```
# export DISPLAY=my.private.ip.address:0
```

This should fail and actually fails, since, this involves accessing a private IP machine from a real IP machine.

This is where I am facing a roadblock and need your help.

**EDIT**

Using `ssh  -X` and `ssh  -Y` failed
with the message,

> X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0

I have checked `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` in remote and 
`X11Forwarding yes` is already there.

**EDIT 2**

Output of `ssh -v -X user@remote.real.ip.address echo Hello world | grep -C 10 "X11 forwarding request failed"`

```
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: exec
debug1: Requesting X11 forwarding with authentication spoofing.
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LC_PAPER = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_ADDRESS = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_MONETARY = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_NUMERIC = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_TELEPHONE = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_IDENTIFICATION = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_MEASUREMENT = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_TIME = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending env LC_NAME = en_US.UTF-8
debug1: Sending command: echo Hello world
debug1: Remote: No xauth program; cannot forward with spoofing.
X11 forwarding request failed on channel 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0
debug1: client_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype eow@openssh.com reply 0
debug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1
debug1: fd 1 clearing O_NONBLOCK
Transferred: sent 3136, received 2800 bytes, in 0.3 seconds
Bytes per second: sent 9839.6, received 8785.3
debug1: Exit status 0
```

Comment: Let's see something like `ssh -v -X any-other-options remote-server echo Hello world | grep -C 10 "X11 forwarding request failed"` for context.

Comment: Please see the edit.

Comment: Okay, that's good; this should be enough for someone to actually write up an answer that helps you. Basically, it looks to me like `xauth` is missing on some end of the SSH pipe (I'm not sure which). Check to make sure it's available in the default $PATH on both systems, just to be sure.

Comment: Indeed, `xauth` was missing in remote. Installed. How do I make that useful?

Comment: Well, does X11 forwarding work for you now, using `ssh -X` or `ssh -Y`?

Comment: Yes, both the options work, but the installer fails.